# Have I misunderstood how to set up Selenium RC with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

I am having difficulty with Selenium RC. When trying to run scripts in Python, I see the message "Cannot import name webdriver".

I'm likely missing something very basic. Let me explain *every* step I've taken (better to be too granular than too vague...):

1. Download and set up Java Development Kit and set Paths. The command 'Java -version' yields "1.6.0_26"
2. Download the Selenium RC standalone server.
3. Started the server
4. Downloaded and installed Python 2.6 32-bit version
5. Downloaded the Python bindings from http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-remote-control-1.0.3.zip. From the zip file, I have copied selenium.py into my Python27\Libs directory.
6. Created a script in Selenium IDE. Exported for Python.

When I try to run the script from IDLE, I see the message "ImportError: cannot import name webdriver". The script I'm using starts

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

I see no definition of a function named 'webdriver' in selenium.py. Is this the wrong file? I am quite confused.

Scripts that don't refer to 'import webdriver' work just fine.

Googling is very unhelpful, and most tutorials are either incomplete or assume a Linux environment (I'm using Windows).

Is this an issue with Selenium 1 vs Selenium 2? Do I need Selenium 2 bindings? Are they different to mine?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebDriver is part of Selenium 2.  You are installing the Selenium 1 bindings and then trying to run WebDriver.  That won't work.

Furthermore, WebDriver API eliminates the need for the Server component (WebDriver is different than Selenium-RC).  To use WebDriver, *All* you need are the Python bindings for Selenium 2.

The easiest way to install them is with pip or easy_install

```
pip install selenium
```

or

```
easy_install selenium
```

Comment: Thank you, Corey. This was all I needed. I should also thank you for the documentation you provide on your blog. Cheers again!